# How to use a specific IP to access specific sites by?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, ip-address, soap-client

My Company registered in certain services on the Web and are relying on the company's IP to use these services, Director asked me to allow some staff to enter these sites from outside the company, after authorized staff enter to comany's site.

How could they use the company's  IP to allow them to browse services sites?

Do I need to use a method such as proxy sites like youtube proxy? or there is another way?How do I do this in asp.net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

You could also create a proxy.

Comment: you r right SLaks, ok how can I make my company server as proxy server?

Comment: I would recommend this instead of my answer however. You will probably need to get in contact with your company's IT department. They would have to set that up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the external services from the IP address of a company server you will have to direct the query from your company IP to the external services on behalf of the employee. The employee would be connecting directly to your company server.

Proxy server may be one way of doing this. You can also re-write your code to forward queries from the company server to the external services on behalf of your user which is what I suggested above. Depends on how deep you would have to go in your code to determine which is better/easier.

Comment: cool shot Phillip, so how can I "direct the query from my company IP to the external services on behalf of the employee"

Comment: I'm making alot of assumptions about your application so I may be off course.

Generally you will have the exployee connect to your server, the server will handle all the authentication and command processing. Then when a exployee tries to access external services, your server would receive that request from the client, the server would then make the outbound connection to the external service, impersonating the employee credentials if needed. your server receives a response back from the external service, your server then forwards it to the client.

If you can do VPN or Proxy you should.

Comment: Basically your client doesn't know anything about the external service, it just connects to the server and the server handles everything between the client and the external service.

Again, my assumption is you developed, or have access to, the code on both the server and the client application.

Comment: The mission has done, thanks for your time Phillip and thanks for SLaks.